# ajax for visitors wordpress

Tags: ajax

I have this code that does ajax in wordpress
it is working fine in admin page but i want it work in the main page of my theme

```
  <?php
   add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

 function my_action_javascript() {
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript" >
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var data = {
    action: 'my_action',
    whatever: 1234
};

                                                                                    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-      ajax.php
  $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
       });
    </script>
 <?php
    }

 add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

 function my_action_callback() {
global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

$whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

$whatever += 10;

    echo $whatever;

die(); // this is required to return a proper result
    }


   add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

Answer (score 3):

You also need to add your action callback to non-privileged users. It works the same way as you registered your `my_action_callback` - you just need to add another line.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

Notice the `wp_ajax_nopriv_` in front of your action - this tells WordPress that any user may call this action., whereas `wp_ajax_` only allows logged in users to run the script.

After properly formatting and cleaning your code, I saw a few things.

- You added the `my_action_callback` twice to the `wp_ajax_my_action`
- You used `admin_footer` instead of `wp_footer` => there was no output on the frontend
- Your `ajaxurl` was not defined

Cleaning all this up, you get your Version working nicely:

```
function my_action_javascript() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var data = {
                action: 'my_action',
                whatever: 1234
            };
            // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-      ajax.php
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    $whatever += 10;
    echo $whatever;
    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

Comment: noting happpend i want the ajax work in the main wordpress page

Comment: See update, and please have a look at the [help section](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) on how to ask questions in this community :)